# Kernel crashes after long iterations

Tags: equation-solving, recursion

I am trying to get a numerical root of a function defined as below. But after some large recursion the kernel get crashed. But for relatively low recursion(10000) that does not make any problem. But I need to do the recursion for about 200000 time. Here I am attaching the code. Anyone please help me to overcome this problem. [image: The code]

```
RootFinderDo[(\[Omega]_)?NumberQ, L_, MAX_, r_, M_, Q_, dQdr_] := (ClearAll[A, B, G, \[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma], \[Delta], S]; \[Alpha][n_] := ((1 - 2*M)/r)*(n*(n + 1)); \[Beta][n_] := -2*n*(I*(\[Omega]/M)*r + (1 - (3*M)/r)*n); \[Gamma][n_] := (1 - (6*M)/r)*n*(n - 1) + (6*M)/r - L*(L + 1); \[Delta][n_] := ((2*M)/r)*(n - 3)*(n + 1);A[0] = -1; B[0] = r*(dQdr/Q + (I*(\[Omega]/M)*r)/(r - 2*M)); A[1] = \[Alpha][1]; B[1] = \[Beta][1]; G[1] = \[Gamma][1]; A[n_] := A[n] = \[Alpha][n]; G[n_] := G[n] = \[Gamma][n] - (B[n - 1]*\[Delta][n])/G[n - 1]; B[n_] := B[n] = \[Beta][n] - (A[n - 1]*\[Delta][n])/G[n - 1]; S[MAX] = G[MAX]/B[MAX];Do[S[n] = G[n + 1]/(B[n + 1] - A[n + 1]*S[n + 1]), {n, MAX - 1, 0, -1}]; RR = B[0] - A[0]*S[0])

\[Omega]guess = 0.0065

Block[{$RecursionLimit = 20000}, FindRoot[RootFinderDo[\[Omega], 2, 15000, 1.2579481679118418*^6, 196567.4968628099, -761321.9343226571 - 24959.124711629214*I, -1.9220363777903136 - 0.06301190533310615*I] == 0, {\[Omega], \[Omega]guess}]]
```

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please add copy-paste-able Mathematica code so that forum participants can copy and paste it to their notebook environments and replicate the errors or difficulties you have encountered. Doing so will enable forum participants to provide you assistance in a focused manner. $\LaTeX$ forms and/or images can be added if these provided added value. Copy directly from your input cell, click the `Edit` button under your post and format as code using the `{  }` icon in the Edit window. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @Syed

Comment: Memoization means your memory use increases with each iteration. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: But other than memoization, the code takes a huge time.

Comment: Max is large and you are working down from there in a loop. Which means memoization will not help to stop deep recursion. So I would expect either the recursion stack to be overrun, or a TerminatedEvaluation to be thrown (in version 13.2).

Comment: Make sure you're not running out of memory.  Add `$HistoryLength=0` at the start of your code unless you wish to keep the history.  And see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Either Stopping memorization or adding $HistoryLength=0 is not working. The kernel is still crashing. Is there anyway other than these?

Comment: Is there any way, where I can break the do loop in more than one part and using the result of previous loop in the next loop, to avoid stacking?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for recursive definitions, you can do everything iteratively:

```
RootFinderDo[ω_?NumberQ, L_, MAX_, r_, M_, Q_, dQdr_] :=
  Module[{A, B, G, α, β, γ, δ, S},
    α[n_] = ((1 - 2*M)/r)*(n*(n + 1));
    β[n_] = -2*n*(I*(ω/M)*r + (1 - (3*M)/r)*n);
    γ[n_] = (1 - (6*M)/r)*n*(n - 1) + (6*M)/r - L*(L + 1);
    δ[n_] = ((2*M)/r)*(n - 3)*(n + 1);
    A[0] = -1;
    A[n_] = α[n]; 
    B[0] = r*(dQdr/Q + (I*(ω/M)*r)/(r - 2*M));
    B[1] = β[1];
    G[1] = γ[1];
    Do[B[n] = β[n] - (A[n - 1]*δ[n])/G[n - 1];
       G[n] = γ[n] - (B[n - 1]*δ[n])/G[n - 1], {n, 2, MAX}];
    S[MAX] = G[MAX]/B[MAX]; 
    Do[S[n] = G[n + 1]/(B[n + 1] - A[n + 1]*S[n + 1]), {n, MAX - 1, 0, -1}];
    B[0] - A[0]*S[0]]
```

Notice that I used [`=`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) everywhere, not [`:=`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html), to make the definitions stick immediately.

Also notice the use of [`Module`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html), which localizes the variables and makes it unnecessary to clean them manually or to take care of the `$HistoryLength` manually.

On the "return trip" there is actually no need to store the values of `S[n]`; we can just keep the "latest" value of `S` in memory:

```
RootFinderDo[ω_?NumberQ, L_, MAX_, r_, M_, Q_, dQdr_] :=
  Module[{A, B, G, α, β, γ, δ, S},
    α[n_] = ((1 - 2*M)/r)*(n*(n + 1));
    β[n_] = -2*n*(I*(ω/M)*r + (1 - (3*M)/r)*n);
    γ[n_] = (1 - (6*M)/r)*n*(n - 1) + (6*M)/r - L*(L + 1);
    δ[n_] = ((2*M)/r)*(n - 3)*(n + 1);
    A[0] = -1;
    A[n_] = α[n]; 
    B[0] = r*(dQdr/Q + (I*(ω/M)*r)/(r - 2*M));
    B[1] = β[1];
    G[1] = γ[1];
    Do[{B[n], G[n]} = {β[n], γ[n]} - {A[n - 1], B[n - 1]}*δ[n]/G[n - 1],
       {n, 2, MAX}];
    S = G[MAX]/B[MAX]; 
    Do[S = G[n + 1]/(B[n + 1] - A[n + 1]*S), {n, MAX - 1, 0, -1}];
    B[0] - A[0]*S]
```

This saves about 10% of time.

I don't think there's a root where you expect it:

```
ReImPlot[RootFinderDo[ω, 2, 15000, 1.2579481679118418*^6, 196567.4968628099,
                      -761321.9343226571 - 24959.124711629214*I,
                      -1.9220363777903136 - 0.06301190533310615*I],
         {ω, 0, 0.01}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Roman. I can understand the problem with my code. I have to check my earlier calculation, to understand, where I made the mistake.